# How configure redirect to api on AWS S3 hosting static website?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, bucket

The idea is basically redirect calls to /api to some origin.
for example  ==> http://my-production-api.com/

I have my html file,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Redirect - API</title>
 <script>
  const api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  fetch(api + '/todos/1')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json)).catch(console.log);

  const ENV_API = '/api';

  fetch(ENV_API + '/todos/1')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json)).catch(console.log);
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app">
  Redirect api
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the next routing rule:

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>/api</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <ReplaceKeyWith>https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

but, the result in console is : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).

thanks for aswer my question!!

Comment: <ReplaceKeyWith>/</ReplaceKeyWith> <HostName>https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</HostName>

Comment: Thanks, @JamesDean

Comment: I can resolve with:                                                                            <RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>api/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <HostName>jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</HostName>
        <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith></ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolved with :

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
<Condition>
    <KeyPrefixEquals>api/</KeyPrefixEquals>
</Condition>
<Redirect>
    <HostName>jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</HostName>
    <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith></ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
</Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```